# Blazor server side Identity Login Page "Not Working"

Tags: authentication, blazor, identity

I have created a Blazor Server side project, which is using Identity for authentication. I have scaffolded the Login page from Identity, as I would like to update the theme, and debug the login process.  However, when I try to use it to log in, I get the error "This page is not working. HTTP 400 ERROR".
Perhaps I have missed something in the startup for configuring cshtml pages, but I have added these lines to Configure Services -

```
services.AddRazorPages();

services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()
```

and the endpoints look ok in Configure-

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
```

Is there something else I could have missed?

Comment: did you add identity default service services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(); ?

Comment: yes, I've done that with this snippet-                 
             services.AddDefaultIdentity<Employee>(options =>
            {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            })
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RepairManagerDbContext>();